# DownloadFile throws Internal Server Error

Tags: c#

This code throws exception. How to fix it?

```
string uriString = "http://www.fileserve.com/login.php";

NameValueCollection postvals = new NameValueCollection();
postvals.Add("loginUserName", "aaaa");
postvals.Add("loginUserPassword", "xxxx");
postvals.Add("autoLogin", "on");
postvals.Add("loginFormSubmit", "Login");

WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.36 Safari/535.7");
myWebClient.UploadValues(uriString, "POST", postvals);

string cookiestr = myWebClient.ResponseHeaders.Get("Set-Cookie");
myWebClient.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookiestr);
myWebClient.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://fileserve.com/file/2jkYtZS"), "C:\\temp\\" + Path.GetFileName("http://www.fileserve.com/file/2jkYtZS/some.avi"));
```

Exception is thrown by myWebClient.DownloadFile() method.:

```
 The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
      at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at SimonDownloader2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Simon\Workspace\C#\Projects\SerialDownloader2\SerialDownloader2\Program.cs:line 32
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Data in the `Set-Cookie` response header is not usually compatible as data for the `Cookie` request header.

Comment: You can always fire up Wireshark and record the traffic. For example, are all POST values uploaded? There is a comment on MSDN which says UploadValues uploads only a single value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadvalues(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Fix the code at the server (if it's yours) or use whatever you're trying to use there correctly.

This isn't an error with `DownloadFile` but the *server* you're connecting to returns the error HTTP 500. So I guess you try something that the server doesn't like. Maybe you're not supposed to login before at least GETting the page or having an appropriate cookie set or whatever.

The easiest way to debug this is probably using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), doing what you're doing there in a browser and watching the interaction and then try figuring out what you do wrong in your code.

Comment: kol: As long as you're dealing with only HTTP Fiddler seems to be a much easier route. No need to dissect the lower protocols, too.

Comment: I used both at my workplace. I just prefer WireShark because there is a lot of other traffic types I have to analyze in addition to HTTP. Fiddler's main advantage is that you can analyze HTTPS traffic, and manipulate it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, that's an issue on the fileserve.com side and unless you run that server too, you won't be able to fix it.

Now, this is possibly happening due to some unexpected parameter that you are sending on your request. I would start by sending less values in that namevalue collection until you pinpoint which one is the culprit.